# Express, Passport and JSON Web Token (jwt) Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, passport.js, passport-local

app.get("/secret", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res){
    res.json({message: "Success! You can not see this without a token"});
});

i will check in postman but response in Unauthorized
Key: Authorization value:JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTExNDMxNjcwfQ.wwt4sY8LDXg_UDqD9-uImdYe0dv-6Ya2IF8WA_Y57Qs

Comment: whats your passport.js file look like?

Comment: please check my full code for below  comment.

Answer (score -1):

var _ = require("lodash");

var express = require("express");

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var passport = require("passport");

var passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");

var ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

var JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

var jwtOptions = {}

jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();

jwtOptions.secretOrKey = 'tasmanianDevil';

var strategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, next) {

```
console.log('payload received', jwt_payload);

// usually this would be a database call:

var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {id: jwt_payload.id})];

if (user) {
    next(null, user);
} else {
    next(null, false);
}
```

});

passport.use(strategy);

var app = express();

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get("/secret", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),

function(req, res){

```
res.json({message: "Success! You can not see this without a token"});
```

});

Comment: are you sure your id in your jwt_payload is coming into `jwt_payload.id` and not `jwt_payload._doc.id` ??